# Average distance between section of piece-wise boundary and surrounding circle

Tags: geometry

I have an arbitrary, closed profile (2D) composed of straight line segments and circular arcs. The profile is intersected by a circle with a known radius and position. For a dynamic model I'm working I need to know the average distance between the part of the profile that is surrounded by the circle and the general circle, according to the following rule:

[Radial line intersecting segmented profile within a circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVY0.png)

Imagine a radial line sweeping around the circle. As it sweeps out the interior area of the circle, it will eventually encounter the profile. The distance between the outer circle (black) and the profile (blue) where it intersects the radial line (purple) is counted as the height (gold). More succinctly, this is the height of the profile along a radial line bounded maximally by the greater circular boundary (and note that I need the average height of the entire bounded profile, not just the height at a single point).

I'll take advice in any platform, but my system is currently being built out in Python.

### What I've tried so far:

It's not to difficult to express a line or arc in polar form. Doing so gives you the radial distance of each point on the segment. For instance, for an line with an arbitrary point *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* and slope *m*,

*r = (y<sub>i</sub> - (m)x<sub>i</sub>) / (sin(θ) - (m)cos(θ))*

The height, h(θ) is given as *R - r*. However, this is just the height at a single angle, θ. I actually need the average, which is given as the integral of the above:

*1 / (b-a) ∫<sub>b</sub><sup>a</sup>(R - r)dθ*

The [analytical solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%2F+%28b-a%29+*+integral+of+%28c+-+md%29+%2F+%28sinx+-+mcosx%29+dx) to this has [multiple trig operations and two square roots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYv43.png)

The equation for an arc-tp-a-circle is even more complex. Since this height needs to be checked multiple times as part of a real-time system, speed is a necessary consideration. Computing this solution multiple times might make this unfeasible. What I hoping for is some way of generalizing the solution to a line or an arc that doesn't require numerically solving tens of thousands of integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put resolve this for the future, I ended up doing a brute force distance calculation using the following process:

1. Convert each segment of the profile into a polar expression (on a polar field with the origin at the center of the major circle).
2. Find the maximum and minimum angles corresponding to the bounded profile.
3. Sample the bounded angle range at *n* points, then calculating the radial distance of each (or any) lines that have a value at the angle for each angle *θ<sub>n</sub>*.
4. For each *θ<sub>n</sub>*, find all the radial values returned. There should be an even number, analogous to a ray traveling through the profile (each radial point corresponds to either entering or leaving the profile). If the number of points is odd, it means that the profile is bounded at *θ<sub>n</sub>* by the primary circle, so append the primary circle radius, *R*, to the list.
5. The total height, *h<sub>n</sub>* of the profile at *θ<sub>n</sub>* is the sum of the difference of each even-odd pair.
6. Find the mean for all the heights *h<sub>n</sub>*.

This isn't the most elegant, and (like any approximation) is prone to error. But it is sufficient for my case. I'd love to know any better, analytically derived algorithms for doing the same!